# How to access the member properties of class that is of list<class> type

Tags: c#, json, api, serialization

Currently I have the following Json which I converted to plain object C# classes. My plain objects class I put them in a ModelMock class where I am trying to access the properties 'name' and 'value'. But I am unable to access and I get and error. The Error I am getting: **'List' does not contain a definition for 'name' and 'value'**

Here is the Json for ref:

```
 {
"matchActionsReasons": [
   {
     "name": "False positive",
     "value": -2147483648
   },
   {
     "name": "Acceptable risk",
     "value": -2147483647
   },
   {
     "name": "Manager approval",
     "value": -2147483646
   }
 ]
}
```

Here is my Model class:

```
public class ModelMock
    {
        public static ModelMock SaveSettingsModel()
        {
            return new ModelMock
            {

                matchActionsReasons =new List<MatchActionsReason>
                {    

                         name = "False positive",  **//Geting the error here**
                         value  = -2147483648      **//Geting the error here**
                }

            };

        }

        public class MatchActionsReason
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int value { get; set; }
        }


            public List<MatchActionsReason> matchActionsReasons { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: I added an answer with the explanation and a link to documentation.  I added a code sample as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must create and add objects of type `MatchActionsReason`:

```
// Using a collection initializer for the list
// and object initializers for the items
matchActionsReasons = new List<MatchActionsReason>{    
    new MatchActionsReason{ name = "False positive", value = -2147483648 }, 
    new MatchActionsReason{ name = "Acceptable risk", value = -2147483647 }, 
    new MatchActionsReason{ name = "Manager approval", value = -2147483646 }
};
```

or

```
// Using Add
matchActionsReasons = new List<MatchActionsReason>();
matchActionsReasons.Add(
    new MatchActionsReason{ name = "False positive", value = -2147483648 }
);
matchActionsReasons.Add(
    new MatchActionsReason{ name = "Acceptable risk", value = -2147483647 }
);  
matchActionsReasons.Add(
    new MatchActionsReason{ name = "Manager approval", value = -2147483646 }
);
```

The `List<T>` class itself does not have `name` and `value` properties. It has, among others, a `Count` property.

You can access member of elements of the list like this:

```
string s = matchActionsReasons[1].name; // ==> "Acceptable risk"
```

or

```
MatchActionsReason mar = matchActionsReasons[1];
string s = mar.name; // ==> "Acceptable risk"
```

Comment: Thank you that did help set the values. however I am getting
"System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object" I think its becuase the new MatchActionsReason instance? Do you how I can fix this?

Comment: I can only guess. When you create an array, say `var a = new MatchActionsReason[20];`, then it is first filled with 20 `null` entries. Also, when you create a class variable, a so called field, it is first initialized with `null`. You must create and assign objects with `new`, before you can access them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it like this:

```
matchActionsReasons =new List<MatchActionsReason>
 {    

       new MatchActionReason
       {
           name = "False positive",
           value  = -2147483648
       },
       add more instances here...          
 }
```

So the complete sample looks like this:

```
public class ModelMock
{
    public static ModelMock SaveSettingsModel()
    {
        return new ModelMock
        {

            matchActionsReasons =new List<MatchActionsReason>
            {    
                 new MatchActionReason
                 {
                     name = "False positive",
                     value  = -2147483648
                 },
                 new MatchActionReason
                 {
                     name = "Another False One",
                     value  = -111111111
                 },
                 add more instances here...   
            }

        };

    }

    public class MatchActionsReason
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }


        public List<MatchActionsReason> matchActionsReasons { get; set; }

}
```

The reason is that when you do new List { put here the new instances }

So in between the brackets you put the instances you are adding to the list.

That is called a collection initializer.

This is Microsoft's documentation for [Obejct and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for providing the answer and docs, I was able to set the values. But when creating the new instances I am getting a null System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Do you how I can get around that?

Comment: @ABIDKHAN where are you getting the exception? I will help you resolve it.

Comment: @ Jonathan Alfaro  when I debug it I am not sure which line is giving me the null reference but I believe its when creating a new instance "new MatchActionReason"

Comment: @ABIDKHAN you need to set breakpoints and step through the code to see where it is happening.  Also if you use the code I posted on my answer you should not be getting any exceptions.  Lastly you need to post entire stack trace of the exception.

Comment: thanks Jonathan I debugged it and fixed the issue. Once again thank you for your help :)

Comment: @ABIDKHAN if my answer solved your original problem please be so kind to mark as answered.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new MatchActionsReason object to your list. Like below.

```
matchActionsReasons = new List<MatchActionsReason>();
matchActionsReasons.Add(new MatchActionsReason(){ name = "foo", value = 115 });
```